# Webpack - Bundle files in a specific sequence

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I would like to **concatenate my .css and .scss files in a specific order**.

For example, I'd like to be able to specify the first file in my build process and move to other directories when that is complete (1st .scss files then .css files). In the end, I'd like to have generated a **single .css** file

I'm just looking for some guidance on where to go and what to read (more specific to my situation) in order to figure this out. I've done a bit of research and haven't found a solution or someone who has tried to do that before.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need to order them in this way? Because if you have both css and scss files, you could just import them in the right order in one scss file.

Comment: That's just a requiremente I need to meet. What do you mean by the right order? What order does Webpack follows when bundling my .css/.scss files into one anyway? That's something I've been trying to figure out too...

Comment: If css or scss or sass files are all imported in one scss or sass file, they will be concatenated in that order. If they are imported in js file, they also will be concatenated in the order of their import.

Comment: Ok, but what's the actual order of import of the files? Is it alphabetical order?

Comment: Webpack reuires you to import your css in js and then extract it in separate files for production. So they will be concatenated in the same order they are imported in js file.

Comment: I see...so it seems there isn't a way to enforce a specific import sequence (.scss and then .css). Thanks! =)